# Why does the .apk file in eclipse keep disappearing when i run it

Tags: android, eclipse

Ok so when i try to run an android app in eclipse, the .apk file disappears from the file list and causes an error. I have searched the internet extensively for other people who might have this issue but haven't found anything.

Please Help!!

Comment: which file list is it disappearing from?

Comment: its disappearing from bin/res

Comment: I'm also using SVN if that changes anything

Answer (score 0):

well if the code/resources (or anything else in the project) has changed , it needs to be re-compiled, so first it needs to delete the old apk and create a new one .

also, please check that you have the latest version of the adt, sdk , and eclipse .

Comment: everything is up to date just installed very recently. but when i compile it, an eclipse pop up says that there is an error and the .apk file is gone.

Comment: what is the error? have you tried to re-download eclipse ? maybe use 64 bit of ecilpse&jdk , and also remember to get 1.6 version of jdk? when you say "an error has occurred" you do know that we need some more info...?

Comment: eclipse says that the "project has errors". just finished reinstalling everything and hasn't changed everything.

Comment: i never had those kind of problems . i had others , but not at this level of magnitude , not on windows and not on linux. anyway, try to create a java project and put there a main class and run it . does it work ? then try to import one of the android api demos projects (instead of creating your own) and see if you can compile and run it . also try to compile an apk from the command line , and install it to a device/emulator via the command line.